# Mocha beforeEach vs before execution

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I ran into a problem recently that I can't explain. I have a lot of code in these tests so I'm going to do my best to capture the idea here

I have tests that look like:

```
describe('main page', function() {
  beforeEach(function(done){
    addUserToMongoDb(done);   // #1
  });

  afterEach(function(done) {
    removeUserFromMongoDb(done);
  });

  context('login', function() {
     it('should log the user in', function() {
       logUserIn(user_email);  // #2 - This line requires the user from the beforeEach
     });
  });

  context('preferences', function() {
    before(function(done) {    //#3
       logUserInBeforeTest(user_email);
     });

    it('should show the preferences', function() {
       doCheckPreferences(); // #4
    });
  });
});
```

The problem is, the beforeEach by `#1` runs fine. I can see it happening on the DB and the tests in `#2` pass.

However, the tests in the preferences context at `#4` fail because it cant find the user to log them in at `#3`.

It seems that the context `before` is executed before the describe `beforeEach`, which causes them to fail. If I move `logUserIn` into the `it` block it works fine.

What could cause this?

Comment: Can't explain why *"It seems that the context before is executed before the describe beforeEach"*, but shouldn't you be executing `done` at some point in that before?

Comment: Before is before the whole block, beforeEach is before each test.

Comment: @StevenScott So thats why then. The describe beforeEach runs after the context before. I wish the documentation made that more obvious

Answer (score 95):

While this answer just shows the documentation notes again, and had some comments to try to help show the difference, the answer below by @tomasz-wszelaki should be refered to.

Mocha's test runner explains this functionality the best in the [Hooks section of the Mocha Test Runner](https://mochajs.org/#hooks).

From the Hooks section:

```
describe('hooks', function() {

    before(function() {
        // runs before all tests in this file regardless where this line is defined.
    });

    after(function() {
        // runs after all tests in this file
    });

    beforeEach(function() {
        // runs before each test in this block
    });

    afterEach(function() {
        // runs after each test in this block
    });

    // test cases
});
```

You can nest these routines within other describe blocks which can also have before/beforeEach routines.

Comment: With respect, the documentation does not explain this behavior very well, as witnessed by the large number of questions on this specific topic. @tomasz-wszelaki's answer is far more enlightening than quoting the documentation verbatim.

Comment: @Aea Thanks for the comment. I read the other answer and it does appear clearer with the example, so I have updated my comments on this issue.  I did not consider the structure that was being done by Tomasz when reproducing the sample.

Answer (score 48):

I found a similar issue. The documentation is misleading because "before this block" means (to me at least) "before this describe section". Meanwhile it means "before any describe section". Check this example:

```js
describe('outer describe', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        console.log('outer describe - beforeEach');
    });

    describe('inner describe 1', function () {
        before(function () {
            console.log('inner describe 1 - before');
        });
    });

    describe('inner describe 2', function () {
        beforeEach(function () {
            console.log('inner describe 2 - beforeEach');
        });
    });
});
```

### Output order:

- *inner describe 1 - before*
- *outer describe - beforeEach*
- *inner describe 2 - beforeEach*

It seems it doesn't matter where in your hierarchy you put the `before` - it will run before any describe and not before its containing describe.

Comment: Think of it as "before each block". This means before each test and before each describe.

Comment: thanks for clarifying! hat was the question I was asking myself because I saw in our projects before() hook defined in nested describe() so people thinks it is run in relationship of the describe context, but it doesn't. Mocha doc could be more precise on that matter and at best, it shouldn't be allowed anywhere else except the topmost describe().

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am shocked to find the Mocha finds this implementation of before more of a feature than a bug. Why on earth doesn't it respect block(describe/context) scope?!

Comment: This example is missing some closing braces. I can't edit it because "there are too many pending edits on StackOverflow"

Answer (score 15):

The reason of confusion is lies in the documentation of mocha.
You can find in [mocha](http://mochajs.org/#hooks):

> Tests can appear before, after, or interspersed with your hooks. Hooks will run in the order they are defined, as appropriate; all before() hooks run (once), then any beforeEach() hooks, tests, any afterEach() hooks, and finally after() hooks (once).

Discussed hooks `before` and `beforeEach` are executed right before all or each `it` respectively - there are no way to execute it before **describe** section.

Here you can [find](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/1628#issuecomment-87289794) answer of the #1 contributor to the mocha's master branch to the idea add something like `beforeDescribe` hook.

I think you should look at the `--delay` mocha [option](http://mochajs.org/#delayed-root-suite).

Answer (score 1):

The key thing is to have `mocha.opts` file with the line pointing on `./test/bootstrap.js`, where you apply before, beforeAll, after, afterAll hooks.

```
Execute all tests:
 - npm test

Execute a single test:
- NODE_ENV=test node --inspect ./node_modules/.bin/_mocha --opts test/mocha.opts test/test/service/unSubscriber.test.js
```

`node --inspect` flag for debugging

---

/package.json

```js
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "engines": {
    "node": "11.9.0",
    "npm": "6.5.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test node --inspect ./node_modules/.bin/_mocha --opts test/mocha.opts test/**/**/**/*.js"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.21.2",
    "mongoose": "^4.5.10",
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "faker": "^4.1.0",
    "mocha": "^6.0.0"
  }
}
```

/test/mocha.opts

```js
--recursive
--timeout 30000
--reporter spec
--file ./test/bootstrap.js
```

/test/bootstrap.js

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config = require('./../service/config').getConfig();
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

before((done) => {
  (async () => {
    const connection = await mongoose.connect(config.mongo_url, { useMongoClient: true });
    await connection.db.dropDatabase();
  })().then(() => {
    require('../server');
    done();
  });
});

after((done) => {
  process.kill(process.pid, 'SIGTERM');
  done();
});
```

/server.js

```js
const http = require('http');
const app = require('./app');
const config = require('./service/config');
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`===== Server running:${config.getEnv()}=====`);
});

process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
  console.log('===== Server closed =====');
  process.exit(0);
});
```

/test/service/unSubscriber.test.js

```js
const faker = require('faker');

const ContactOptOutRepository = require('../../repository/contactOptOut');
const UnSubscriber = require('../../service/unSubscriber');
const expect = require('chai').expect;

const contactOptOutRepository = new ContactOptOutRepository();
const unSubscriber = new UnSubscriber();

const emails = [
  faker.internet.email(),
  faker.internet.email(),
  faker.internet.email(),
  faker.internet.email(),
  faker.internet.email(),
];

describe('UnSubscriber', () => {
  it('should filter out unsubscribed emails', () => {
    return (async () => {
      await contactOptOutRepository.newUnSubscription(emails[0], faker.lorem.word());
      await contactOptOutRepository.newUnSubscription(emails[1], faker.lorem.word());
      await contactOptOutRepository.newUnSubscription(emails[2], faker.lorem.word());

      return await unSubscriber.filterUnsubscribed(emails);
    })()
      .then(filtered => {
        expect(filtered.length).to.be.equal(2);
      });
  });
});
```