# Mocha - Which runs first, beforeEach or before?

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js

I have a web app with a spec like this:

```
describe('Hook them up', () => {

    var server;

    beforeEach(done => {
        server = app.listen(done);
    });

    before(done => {
       // Does this run before or after "beforeEach"
       // If I try to access the api at this point I get an ECONNREFUSED
    });

    after(done => {
        server.close(done);
    });


    it('should set the \'createdAt\' property for \'DndUsers\' objects', done => {
        api.post('/api/tweets')
            .send({ text: 'Hello World' })
            .then(done)
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
                done();
            });
    });
});
```

In some other project of mine, if I try to access the api in the `before` block it works fine, as if the `beforeEach` was already run.

Answer (score 4):

[See my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32660241/mocha-beforeeach-vs-before-execution/32682451#32682451) to a very similar question.

Mocha's test runner explains this functionality the best in the [Hooks section of the Mocha Test Runner](https://mochajs.org/#hooks).

From the Hooks section:

```
describe('hooks', function() {

    before(function() {
        // runs before all tests in this block
    });

    after(function() {
        // runs after all tests in this block
    });

    beforeEach(function() {
        // runs before each test in this block
    });

    afterEach(function() {
        // runs after each test in this block
    });

    // test cases
    it(...);  // Test 1
    it(...);  // Test 2
});
```

You can nest these routines within other describe blocks which can also have before/beforeEach routines.

This should give you

```
hooks
    before
        beforeEach
            Test 1
        afterEach
        beforeEach
            Test 2
        afterEach
    after
```