# Execute BeforeEach Hook before Before Hook in Mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I want to create a `beforeEach` Hook that is executed before a `before` Hook.

Basically I want the following behaviour:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  console.log('beforeEach')
})

describe('tests', () => {
  before(() => {
    console.log('before')
  })

  it('test 1', () => {
    console.log('it')
  })
})
```

And I get:

```
before
beforeEach
it
```

But the output I want is:

```
beforeEach
before
it
```

What would be the correct structure to get the desired behaviour?

**Workaround**

Currently I found a workaround using two nested beforeEach:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  console.log('beforeEach1')
})

describe('tests', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    console.log('beforeEach2')
  })

  it('test 1', () => {
    console.log('it')
  })
})
```

Which output is:

```
beforeEach1
beforeEach2
it
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure of this (I have not tested it) but from the [doc](https://mochajs.org/#run-cycle-overview) it seems that your root-level `beforeEach` probably does not do what you may think.

```
...
run spec file/s
  |
  |--------------> per spec file
    suite callbacks (e.g., 'describe')
    |
    'before' root-level pre-hook
    |
    'before' pre-hook
    |
    |--------------> per test
      'beforeEach' root-level pre-hook
      |
      'beforeEach' pre-hook
      ...
```

From the above picture, you can see that for each `describe` the `before` root-level pre-hook is called. Just turn your root-level `beforeEach` in a `before` and it should be solved.

The general rule is that `before` callback always come "before"(no pun intended) the `beforeEach` callback, independently from the level they are defined in.

Comment: Thanks, I indeed checked the docs. The problem is that I need a general beforeEach that should be executed for every test (creates the general database schemas needed for every test). And every test has a particular 'before' to set the different cases at the database.

Comment: You described what you did with the "workaround", why is it not correct in your situation? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Because beforeEach2 should be executed just once before the individual test (this one is so simple, but could exist other more complex). Also the syntax is confusing for other contributors. I thought it would exist a clear correct structure for my case

Comment: You should not worry about confusing other contributors. This is the logic that mocha developer chose to follow and you perfectly stick to it, there is not a more clear solution. You solved it yourself.

Comment: Finally found this similar question with more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32660241/mocha-beforeeach-vs-before-execution. Seems actually really limited

Answer (score 0):

You could use a describe() that has a beforeEach() and a describe() inside of it.

Something like this

```
describe ('A blah component', () => 
{
  beforeEach(() => {
    console.log('beforeEach')
  })

   describe(`tests`, () => {
     before(() => {
       console.log('before')
     })

     it('test 1, () => {
       console.log('it')
     })
   })
}
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately Im getting the same behaviour: `before >
beforeEach >
it`

Comment: Mocha has an implied `describe` block. In this way you are only adding an empty level.